# would it be possible to use archive-movies-title.php

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

I have a custom post type movies and what I am trying to do is list the movie titles in order of initial letter, which works if I create 36 .php files .eg title-a, title-b ....

```
<div class="row pbot ptop" style="color: #fff;"><!-- #### ROW #### --> 
<div class="align_Center">
<?php
    $args = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","ALL");
?>
<?php
    for($x = 0; $x < 36; $x++) {
?>
<span style="color: #777;">|</span>
<a href="title-<?php echo $args[$x]; ?>" class="m_headr"><?php echo $args[$x]; ?></a>
<?php
    }
?>
<span style="color: #777;">|</span>
</div>
</div><!-- #### / ROW #### -->
```

Is there any way that I can do it all through a single file called .eg archive-movies-title and with a loop containing get_queried_object()->name. I don't know if I am close to the mark or I am fishing without a rod.

Comment: is the array $args representing the movie titles?

Comment: yes they are representing the movie titles, hence the 36 php files... just want it simplified into one file

Comment: Right now you are creating 36 <a href=""></a> tags not files.

Comment: Yes but I have already created the 36 .php files and I am just creating links to them. But is there no way I can link all the hyperlinks into one file .eg title-list.php rather than 36 files, so that query within the loop can decipher what link the user pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand what you want to do is have a list of links to the same php file and then this  php file determines which link the user has pressed.

To do this you could use query strings i.e. title-list.php?title=0 , title-list.php?title=1 etc.

The title-list.php file will then recieve query string variable of title. Basically what you will have to do is have a link to the same php file however the querystring will be different for each different movie title that way your title-list.php will be able to determine what link the user has clicked.

So your original code will be this.

```
 <div class="row pbot ptop" style="color: #fff;"><!-- #### ROW #### --> 
    <div class="align_Center">
    <?php
        $args = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","ALL");

    ?>
    <?php
        for($x = 0; $x < 36; $x++) {
    ?>
    <span style="color: #777;">|</span>
    <a href="title-list.php?title=<?php echo $args[$x]; ?>" class="m_headr"><?php echo $args[$x]; ?></a> <!--This line has changed-->
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <span style="color: #777;">|</span>
    </div>
    </div><!-- #### / ROW #### -->
```

Then in your title-list.php file add this

```
<?php
   /* 
    * header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/". $_GET['title'] . ".php" );//if you want to redirect to the php file uncomment this
    */
   echo $_GET['title'];  //this will output the movie title              
?>
```

I hope this helps, however your question is still a little unclear to me so I have tried to answer it as best I could.

Comment: No problem mate :-)